# Android: how to use color from style in XML of another layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme

I got this style in **XML**:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_500</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/teal_700</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_blue_500</item>

        <!-- needed to suppress the old ActionBar when using the new Toolbar -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Question:**

And inside the **XML** of a `Fragment` I'm using `TextView` onto which I would like to assign `"colorPrimary"` from the theme. But how?

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/text_input"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"   <!-- use theme color here-->
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
              android:text="some text"
              android:textSize="24dp"/>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/text_input"
              android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"   
              android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
              android:text="some text"
              android:textSize="24dp"/>
```

Comment: Alhamdulillah, jajakumullah, You Saved My Two Days !